# cleartextTrafficPermitted does'nt work as i hope

Tags: android, kotlin, security, https, retrofit

My apk worked before, but the backend dev had made some updates(JWT and https the server). However, the error when i execute my android app in an emulator (with API version 34) is this:

FATAL EXCEPTION: DefaultDispatcher-worker-2
Process: com.example.labiofam_android, PID: 14273
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.
at com.android.org.conscrypt.SSLUtils.toSSLHandshakeException(SSLUtils.java:356)...

I have this code in res/network_security_config.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
    <domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">127.0.0.1</domain>
    </domain-config>
</network-security-config>
```

and in AndroidManifest.xml i have this:
`android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config" android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"`

my api is local, i'm sure that my server works, because i make queries from postman or swagger and the server responds as well. I'm using retrofit to connect with the server, and the configuration is the following code:

```
val baseUrl = "https://10.0.2.2:5263/api/"
    fun getInstance(): Retrofit {
        return Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(baseUrl)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .callFactory(OkHttpClient.Builder().callTimeout(60,TimeUnit.SECONDS).build())
            .build()

    }
```

I want that my apk works although it's unsecure.

Comment: `in AndroidManifest.xml i have this: android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config" ` Remove that.